# PySpark: Compare columns of one df with the rows of a second df

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to compare two PySpark dataframes.

I have Df1 with hundreds of columns (Col1, Col2, ..., Col800) and Df2 with hundreds of corresponding rows.

The Df2 describes the limit values for each of the 800 columns in Df1, if the value is too low or too high, then I would like to achieve the result in Final_Df, where I create a column `Problem` which checks if any of the columns is out of limits.

I thought about transposing Df2 with pivot, but it requires an aggregate function, so I am not sure if it is a relevant solution.

I also don't see how I could join the two Dfs for the comparison, since they don't share any common column.

Df1:

```
| X         | Y         | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+
| Value_X_1 | Value_Y_1 | 5000 | 250  | 500  |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+
| Value_X_2 | Value_Y_2 | 1000 | 30   | 300  |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+
| Value_X_3 | Value_Y_3 | 0    | 100  | 100  |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+
```

Df2:

```
+------+------+-----+
| name | max  | min |
+------+------+-----+
| Col1 | 2500 | 0   |
+------+------+-----+
| Col2 | 120  | 0   |
+------+------+-----+
| Col3 | 400  | 0   |
+------+------+-----+
```

Final_Df (after comparison):

```
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+---------+
| X         | Y         | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Problem |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+---------+
| Value_X_1 | Value_Y_1 | 5000 | 250  | 500  | Yes     |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+---------+
| Value_X_2 | Value_Y_2 | 1000 | 30   | 300  | No      |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+---------+
| Value_X_3 | Value_Y_3 | 0    | 100  | 100  | No      |
+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `df2` is not a big dataframe, you can convert it to a dictionary and then use list comprehension and **when** function to check the status, for example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

>>> df1.show()
+---------+---------+----+----+----+
|        X|        Y|Col1|Col2|Col3|
+---------+---------+----+----+----+
|Value_X_1|Value_Y_1|5000| 250| 500|
|Value_X_2|Value_Y_2|1000|  30| 300|
|Value_X_3|Value_Y_3|   0| 100| 100|
+---------+---------+----+----+----+

>>> df2.show()
+----+----+---+
|name| max|min|
+----+----+---+
|Col1|2500|  0|
|Col2| 120|  0|
|Col3| 400|  0|
+----+----+---+

# concerned columns
cols = df1.columns[2:]
>>> cols
['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']
```

> Note: I assumed data types already set to integer for the above cols in df1 and df2.min, df2.max.

Create a map from df2:

```
map1 = { r.name:[r.min, r.max] for r in df2.collect() }

>>> map1
{u'Col1': [0, 2500], u'Col2': [0, 120], u'Col3': [0, 400]}
```

Add new field 'Problem' based on two when() functions, use a list comprehension to iterate through all concerned columns

> - F.when(df1[c].between(min, max), 0).otherwise(1))
> - F.when(sum(...) > 0, 'Yes').otherwise('No')

We set a flag(0 or 1) with the first `when()` function for each concerned column, and then take the sum on this flag. if it's greater than 0 then Problem = 'Yes', otherwise 'No':

```
df_new = df1.withColumn('Problem', F.when(sum([ F.when(df1[c].between(map1[c][0], map1[c][1]), 0).otherwise(1) for c in cols ]) > 0, 'Yes').otherwise('No'))

>>> df_new.show()
+---------+---------+----+----+----+-------+
|        X|        Y|Col1|Col2|Col3|Problem|
+---------+---------+----+----+----+-------+
|Value_X_1|Value_Y_1|5000| 250| 500|    Yes|
|Value_X_2|Value_Y_2|1000|  30| 300|     No|
|Value_X_3|Value_Y_3|   0| 100| 100|     No|
+---------+---------+----+----+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using UDF and dictionary I was able to solve it. Let me know if its helpful.

```
#  Create a map like, name -> max#min
df = df.withColumn('name_max_min',F.create_map('name',F.concat( col('max'), lit("#"), col('min')) ))

# HANDLE THE null 
# you can try this ,not sure about this , but python has math.inf which 
# supplies both infinities
positiveInf = float("inf")
negativeInf = float("-inf")

df = df.fillna({ 'max':999999999, 'min':-999999999  })

### df is :
+----+----+---+-------------------+
|name| max|min|       name_max_min|
+----+----+---+-------------------+
|Col1|2500|  0|Map(Col1 -> 2500#0)|
|Col2| 120|  0| Map(Col2 -> 120#0)|
|Col3| 400|  0| Map(Col3 -> 400#0)|
+----+----+---+-------------------+

#  Create a dictionary out of it
v = df.select('name_max_min').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

keys = []
values = []
for p in v:
    for r, s in p.items():
        keys.append(str(r).strip())  
        values.append(str(s).strip().split('#'))

max_dict = dict(zip(keys,values))
#  max_dict = {'Col1': ['2500', '0'], 'Col2': ['120', '0'], 'Col3': ['400', '0']}

#  Create a UDF which can help you to assess the conditions.
def problem_udf(c1):
        #  GENERAL WAY 
        #  if the column names are diff
        #p =all([int(max_dict.get(r)[1]) <= int(c1[r]) <= int(max_dict.get(r)[0]) for r in c1.__fields__])

        p = all([ int(max_dict.get("Col" + str(r))[1]) <= int(c1["Col" + str(r)]) <= int(max_dict.get("Col" + str(r))[0])  for r in range(1, len(c1) + 1)])
        if p :
            return("No")
        else:
            return("Yes")


callnewColsUdf= F.udf(problem_udf, StringType())


col_names = ['Col'+str(i) for i in range(1,4)]
# GENERAL WAY
# col_names = df1.schema.names

df1 = df1.withColumn('Problem', callnewColsUdf(F.struct(col_names)))


## Results in :
+---------+---------+----+----+----+-------+
|        X|        Y|Col1|Col2|Col3|Problem|
+---------+---------+----+----+----+-------+
|Value_X_1|Value_Y_1|5000| 250| 500|    Yes|
|Value_X_2|Value_Y_2|1000|  30| 300|     No|
|Value_X_3|Value_X_3|   0| 100| 100|     No|
+---------+---------+----+----+----+-------+
```

Comment: There are more than 800 columns. A generalized solution would help.

Comment: Thank you @Preetham for a very clever solution, it works as intended, but I am still trying to tweak it so I don't have to write 800 checks in the problem_udf.

Comment: Also, sorry I forgot to point out that some of the max or min values in the Df2 are null and if that happens then the Df1 column should only be evaluated against the non-null value. Currently, by using your solution the mapping in the name_max_min column doesn't register the non-null column, eg. Df2: Col4, null, 0. name_max_min: [Col4->]. I thought about replacing nulls in the max column by something like 999999999 and the nulls in min by -999999999, but is there a more robust solution?

Comment: Have done the changes to my best !! Let me know if its usefull.